# Is it possible to get 3 success markers on an unopposed story?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-lcg

Played my first game of Call of Cthulhu: The Card Game the other day and I was able to get 3 success tokens out of the 5 required from my first story due to the other player not having any characters on the board.

I played a character that had one investigator icon, which means he wins the investigation struggle and gets a success token, and then he wins another success token for having the most skill, and then the third for the story being unopposed.

Is this correct? Would you still get three tokens even though the character does not have an investigation icon?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've played this (which is why this is a comment, and not an answer), but your summary looks correct. You get one for having the most Skill; and a second because you won unopposed. As for struggles,you'll only win them if you have more icons than your opponent, so a character with no Investigate icons will net you 2 tokens if it's unopposoed at a story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing this a lot more times and going through the rules as well, this is the case.

Winning an investigation icon gives you one success token immediately.
Winning the story based on the skills of your committed characters gives you another, and finally, if at the end there are no opposing characters on the story, you get another success token for winning unopposed